# Can't filter here.com autosuggest API by category

Tags: here-api

I'm trying out the places autosuggest api in here.com, but filtering by `education-facility` category doesn't seem to work:

```
https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?app_id=...&q=strathcona&app_code=...&at=53.631611,-113.323975&category=education-facility
```

The [here.com categories documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/categories.html) is a little unclear about what is supported and what is not, but it seems like I should be able to use [education-facility](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/place_categories/category-800-facilities.html).  And it's also unclear from the documentation whether I should use the words `Educational Facility`, or whether I should use the canonical `education-facility`.  In fact, even explicitly-supported categories like `restaurant` seem to have no effect.

Posting here because [stack overflow is the place for tech support](https://developer.here.com/contact-us).

*Edit*: By "doesn't seem to work", I should have specified that I didn't see any schools, only categories like `city-town-village`, `administrative-region`, `airport` etc.

Answer (score 0):

A request to the Places (Search) API includes the basic elements like base URL and pathname ,in addition, may contain resource-specific parameters.
The resource-specific parameters in url can either be autosuggest(that you have used) or categories/places (and many more), please refer developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/request-constructing.html

The attributes which can be passed in autosuggest API can be referred from : 
developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics_api/media-type-autosuggest.html

eg. Under Suggested Place
You can use category and categoryTitle like below. The canonical form and also local category names specified in different categories option can work(developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/place_categories/places-category-system.html)

**category**    String; (optional) - A category id or name for this place.

**categoryTitle**   String  - The (localized) display name of the category. For example, Eat & Drink.

The only mandatory attributes for autosuggest resource-type in Rest URL are

1) **q** : which is the search text 
2) **at** : which specifies the lat and long

For autosuggest resource-type in API :

https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest?app_id=xxxxxx&app_code=yyyyyyy&at=53.631611,-113.323975&category=education-facility&q=edu

For category resource-type in API:

https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/categories/places?app_id=xxxxxx&app_code=yyyyyy&categoryId=eat-drink&at=53.631611,-113.323975&category=eat and drink

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more explicit about what I was seeing.  I have essentially the same URL as what you suggest, but I'm seeing categories like `city-town-village`, `administrative-region`, `airport` etc. but no schools.  I'm explicitly trying to find a known entity, "Strathcona High School" that exists near those coordinates.